# this is showing syntax error in update statement.please anybody resolve it

Tags: c#

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        string query = "update pkemp set pno=@pno, name=@name,plant=@plant,section=@section,designation=@designation,cell=@cell, address=@address where pno=@pno";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pno", txtpno.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plant", txtplant.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", txtsection.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtdesignation.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", txtcell.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);

        long a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            reset();
            display();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Not Updated", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

i am trying to update but error is "Syntax error in update statment"

Comment: I doubt the error is `Syntax error in update statment` (with a typo). Please *paste* in the error and the relevant traceback.

Comment: Where does that OleDbConnection go to? Ms Access? Excel? Oracle? pgsql? mariadb? SAP?

Comment: i am using ms access database.please resolve it

Comment: yes the erre is "Syntax error in update statement"

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you write the `query` like this;

```
string query = "update [pkemp] set [pno]=@pno, [name]=@name,[plant]=@plant,[section]=@section,[designation]=@designation,[cell]=@cell, [address]=@address where [pno]=@pno";
```

Comment: string query = "update pkemp set [name]=@name, [plant]=@plant, [section]=@section, [designation]=@designation, [cell]=@cell,

Comment: not working by written this also

Comment: The query you sent is incomplete, it is very difficult for us to solve the problem if you do not provide correct information.

Comment: thank you so so so so so so so so so so much,you resolved my huge problem

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can support me by accepting my answer and upvoting it. Cheers :)

Comment: Don't forget to close the connection after the process is finished via `con.Close()`. Connection should not remain open.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should add blank after comma.

```
pno=@pno,  name=@name,  plant=@plant,  section=@section, 
     designation=@designation,  cell=@cell, address=@address
```

Comment: sir i have given space after comma but error is same

Comment: sir i do that as you written but error is still same